# How to save the open/closed state of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

I've made a component that visualizes an object where array's and nested objects are collapsible.

It works by looping through all the keys/indexes and using the appropriate render function. Right now the collapse and extend actions are purely CSS class-based.

The issue I have right now is that I need to make it so the collapsed/extended state persists. So basically I need a way to store the collapsed state info. and read it later on. I'm not really sure how to even start.

The state should persist even when the object is modified. So when an new item gets pushed in the middle of the array it should still open the same thing. What data structure should I use for this and how would I read it?

The reason I'm not posting any code is that I don't think it's necessary, I'm purely interested in how the data should be structured for the collapsed/extended state of an array/object so it persists when updates are made to the object/array.

I've tried making some type of "breadcrumbs" that follow the structure of the object but then I realized that it won't persist when changes are made.

Any ideas? Is this even possible without some hardcoded unique ids?

Comment: You do not have JSON. You have an object. JSON is a string

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+keep+state+collapsed+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

***Edit 1:** point 4 it's not optimal and can be done better - after you finish rendering the main object to the DOM, loop through the state object and for each path, find the DOM node and expand it.*

***Edit 2:** instead of 'index1.nestedIndex2[1].nestedIndex3' you can do 'index1.nestedIndex2.1.nestedIndex3', makes your code simpler*

***Edit 3:** no need to use lodash (edited point 1)*

I hope I understood your scenario correctly.

In order to persist the expanded (or collapsed) state, you have to:

1. create an object that stores the paths to the indexs that you want expanded, like this `{'index1.nestedIndex2[1].nestedIndex3': true}`. You can do this when clicking to expand. Of course, this means you should know the current index and it's parents when you click - one way to do this is by having a DOM attribute holding the index, on each element. So when you click a node to go up recursively until you reach the top element, and build that string path
2. Convert the state object to a string using `JSON.stringify` and store it in localStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). `localStorage.set('expandedState', JSON.stringify(stateObject))`. If you need to store the state for multiple data objects, you have to use some specific key instead of 'expandedState'
3. In the code, before rendering the main object, convert the string state from localStorage back to an object using `JSON.parse`
4. While rendering your main object, you have to build the path for the currently rendered node and check if it can be found in the state object. If yes, expand it by adding your css class on it. To build back the path, it's more optimal to build it as you render each node rather than using the same method used in point 1, but that would also work (but slower, so for really big objects will be a problem, I think)